# 400 bad request in post request from client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http-status-code-400

I am building an app using nodejs, react, postgresql.

***server.js***

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());


app.post("/todos",async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const {description} =  req.body;
        const newStudent = await pool.query(
            "INSERT INTO todo (description) VALUES($1) RETURNING *",
            [description]
        );
        res.json(newStudent.rows[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})
```

in ***reactcomponent.js***

```
try {
      const body = values.firstName;
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/todos",{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      });
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
```

here value.firstName is something that is taken from form input. and ***create database table*** sql command -

```
CREATE TABLE todo(
todo_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  description VARCHAR(255)
);
```

when i check ***console*** i get this -

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:5000/todos", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

using postman, i am able to interact with my postgres database and execute request properly.
i need help because it is not working on client side. how can i solve this?

Comment: there is a similar problem to yours, maybe do check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585009/post-400-bad-request-when-clicking-fast

Comment: this does not solve my issue

Comment: It looks like you are passing the `firstName` property via POST but trying to destructure a `description` property on the backend that might not be there. What is the structure of the `body` on the front end?

Comment: `values.firstName` is something that i get from input form. i want to set this as description.

`const [values,setValues] = useState({
        firstName : "",
        lastName : "",
        email : "",
        password: "",
        registration:"",
      });`
this is the object from frontend

Comment: i have 5 input forms and one is firstName

Answer (score 0):

could it be that maybe from the server side you are retrieving it as plain text? if so do change it from `application/json` to `text/plain`
I hope this helps.

---

(I am editing here since in comment the code won't be visible)

---

I found a code similar to yours for add
I do think the request is wrong here.

```
app.post('/users', (req, res)=> {
    const user = req.body;
    let insertQuery = `insert into users(id, firstname, lastname, location) 
                       values(${user.id}, '${user.firstname}', '${user.lastname}', '${user.location}')`

    client.query(insertQuery, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send('Insertion was successful')
        }
        else{ console.log(err.message) }
    })
    client.end;
})
```

Comment: it works. but the attribute is not setting as i am taking `values.firstName` and want to put this value as ` description` attribute in table

Comment: after the change you suggested, i kept the code as it is. now it is entering values in database with null values. what might be the reason here?

Comment: the issue was in the state naming. i guess i have to name them according to table attribute. thanks for your help

Comment: anytime i hope it worked !